# RegEnumkeyEx for xml

Tags: xml, registry, msxml

```
<computer>
      <Keyboard/>
      <Mouse/>
      <HardDisk/>
</computer>
```

Here , assume xml as a registry ,computer is a registry key, and it have keyboard,mouse,harddisk ,these are subkeys to computer. Now can u help me, how can enumerate a subkey from xml using MSXML and registry function.

Comment: In other words, you are trying to use RegEnumKeyEx on a structure that represents what you're showing here - e.g. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Computer\Keyboard ?

Comment: @raja - Want do you exactly want to do? Can you explain more? do you want to enumerate computer hardwares? Or you want to write registry into a XML?